# Ignore first render in swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, data-binding, observableobject

I am trying to show an error below a text field. if the value of text fields is less then 2 character we show an error.

The only problem is that the value must be initialised ie with empty string which triggers the error with out even the beginning of user interaction. Code is attached for reference.

```
class ErrorViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var value: String
    var errorToShow: String {
        if(value.count < 2){
            return "invalid input"
        }else{
            return ""
        }
    }
    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
struct ErrorView: View {
    @ObservedObject var errorVm: ErrorViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text(errorVm.errorToShow)
    }
}

struct TextFieldView : View {
    @State var value: String
    var body: some View {
        TextField(
            "Enter yor name",
            text: $value
        )
        ErrorView(errorVm: ErrorViewModel.init(value: value))
    }
}

#Preview {
    TextFieldView(value: "")
}
```

I just want to ignore the first render with the default value. So that the error is shown when user interaction begins.

Comment: I think you should try to use the state management you have an available to you as it stands. Since you have your Published property, you might be able to use something like 'onChange' to watch for a change. Within that check, you can see if the newValue meets your criteria, and if not set the error. This way the UI will respond to all cases, and if you craft it properly, it won’t show an error off the bat

Answer (score 0):

You should write the logic as you think of, so keep track of the `user interaction` as well, for example like:

```
struct TextFieldView : View {
    @State var value: String
    @State var userInteracted = false //  keep tracking
    var body: some View {
        TextField(
            "Enter yor name",
            text: Binding(get: { value ?? "" }, set: { value = $0 })
        )
        .onChange(of: value) { _, _ in userInteracted = true } //  toggle on interactions

        if userInteracted { //  make this conditional
            ErrorView(errorVm: ErrorViewModel.init(value: value))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/focused(_:))) :

```
struct TextFieldView : View {
    @State var value: String = ""
    @FocusState var editing: Bool

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter yor name", text: $value)
            .focused($editing)

        if editing {
            ErrorView(errorVm: ErrorViewModel.init(value: value))
        }
    }
}
```